# US Fire Database

Tags: usa, database, fire

I am searching for a website that will allow me to find wildfires/forest fire/small fires in the United States that has all the information in a database. What I would like to look it up the database to look for each fire incident.

Comment: @albert Strange edit [We don't use Title Case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98069/189029)

Comment: Where is that established? I think its odd that that is not the norm.

Answer (score 4):

If you're fine with textual or GIS data, you'll probably find it in the NASA [VIIRS Active Fire Data](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/earth-observation-data/near-real-time/firms/active-fire-data) page. It's updated frequently and contains worldwide fire hotspots of the past 24 hours up to one week.

There's also an archive for older data.

Comment: That is a very good. Once I get back on the fires at my work I will come back here and check on it.

Answer (score 3):

Two U.S. federal options:
[InciWeb - Incident Information System - National Wildfire Coordinating Group (NWCG)](http://inciweb.nwcg.gov/)
[Wildfire - Wildland Fire Information](http://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/firehistory/data.html)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what year(s) or what information you are looking for, which are significant factors for what source to go to.  If you want especially detailed data about fire perimeters and how they change over time, you might find [SimTable](https://www.simtable.com/active-fire/) or [GeoMac](https://www.geomac.gov/) useful for your efforts.

Comment: Actually I said "all the information in a database", so it should be all the years since the wildfire stared....however you are right I could have said this  what year....BTW, thanks for the link SimTable looks nicely...

Comment: "all information" is pretty vague.  Fire data is often specific to the user type.  If you add more particulars about what data you expect to find, I could probably point you in a better direction.