# Seeking remote sensing dataset for fire perimeter by hour in California

Tags: usa, real-time, fire

If anyone has worked with Cal Fire Perimeter dataset, can you advise what will be a good data source to get hourly California Fire perimeter, by date and by location, from 2010s and later?

I am looking for a dataset that will give me the timestamp and the location, in term of longitude and latitude, when a fire occurs. I did look at NASA VIIRS Active Fire Data to get active fire hotspot. However, when I compared the data I got from there with Cal Fire Perimeter dataset, I noticed that NASA VIIRS Active Fire Data did not contain all of the fire's hotspot when it occurs. Thus, to get a more accurate picture of the fire's spreading time, I just wonder if anyone has any recommendations on what dataset I should use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of them that may what you are looking for. You said Cal Fire Perimeter and indicate that you wanted focus on California ?

The USFS has their Forest Service in California.

The other one is Interagency

https://www.fs.usda.gov/science-technology/fire/information

https://egp.nwcg.gov/egp/

Plus, here is my question I had in the past here :

[US Fire Database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/us-fire-database)

https://fsapps.nwcg.gov/

Also you might find them in ArcGIS Online . ArcGIS Hubs

In the past, I post my question about Fire data

[US Fire Database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/us-fire-database)